# Django showing error (A server error occurred. Please contact the administrator.) when trying to access the local server (127.0.0.1:800)

Tags: python, django, server

I am totally new to this. I am running the version 1.8 of Django. The error it shows in console is:

```
F:\django\mysite>python manage.py runserver
```

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
April 10, 2015 - 19:09:15
Django version 1.8, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers
\base.py", line 119, in get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresol
vers.py", line 388, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.core.urlresolvers.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<RegexURLResolver <RegexURLPat
tern list> (admin:admin) ^admin/>]], 'path': ''}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: could not convert string to float: title

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in
 run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\stati
cfiles\handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers
\wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers
\base.py", line 173, in get_response
    response = debug.technical_404_response(request, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.p
y", line 542, in technical_404_response
    return default_urlconf(request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.p
y", line 581, in default_urlconf
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(DEFAULT_URLCONF_TEMPLATE)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\engi
ne.py", line 153, in from_string
    return Template(template_code, engine=self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\base
.py", line 190, in __init__
    self.nodelist = engine.compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\engi
ne.py", line 261, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\base
.py", line 317, in parse
    filter_expression = self.compile_filter(token.contents)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\base
.py", line 423, in compile_filter
    return FilterExpression(token, self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\base
.py", line 624, in __init__
    var_obj = Variable(var)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\base
.py", line 752, in __init__
    self.literal = float(var)
SystemError: result with error in PyObject_Call
[10/Apr/2015 19:09:21]"GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers
\base.py", line 119, in get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\urlresol
vers.py", line 388, in resolve
    raise Resolver404({'tried': tried, 'path': new_path})
django.core.urlresolvers.Resolver404: {'tried': [[<RegexURLResolver <RegexURLPat
tern list> (admin:admin) ^admin/>]], 'path': 'favicon.ico'}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
ValueError: could not convert string to float: request.path_info

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in
 run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\stati
cfiles\handlers.py", line 63, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers
\wsgi.py", line 189, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers
\base.py", line 173, in get_response
    response = debug.technical_404_response(request, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\views\debug.p
y", line 565, in technical_404_response
    t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(TECHNICAL_404_TEMPLATE)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\engi
ne.py", line 153, in from_string
    return Template(template_code, engine=self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\base
.py", line 190, in __init__
    self.nodelist = engine.compile_string(template_string, origin)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\engi
ne.py", line 261, in compile_string
    return parser.parse()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\base
.py", line 317, in parse
    filter_expression = self.compile_filter(token.contents)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\base
.py", line 423, in compile_filter
    return FilterExpression(token, self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\base
.py", line 624, in __init__
    var_obj = Variable(var)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages\django\template\base
.py", line 752, in __init__
    self.literal = float(var)
SystemError: result with error in PyObject_Call
[10/Apr/2015 19:09:23]"GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Answer (score 0):

Reads the errors...all is written there...

```
"ValueError: could not convert string to float: title"
"ValueError: could not convert string to float: request.path_info"
```

Check your files (settings.py, urls.py...)

Comment: Yes I had noticed those error messages. But I'm not really sure what exactly to look for in those files or why it needs to convert a string to a float.

Answer (score 0):

check your settings.py, urls.py, views.py.

there is a value error for a variable **title**